# Amazon S3 Upload error SSL certificate issues

Tags: amazon-s3, laravel-5

I'm trying to test Laravel Amazon S3 on my localhost but keep getting the same error:

> S3Exception in WrappedHttpHandler.php line 192: Error executing
> "ListObjects" on
> "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app?prefix=appimages%2FIMG-1469840859-j.jpg%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url";
> AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get
> local issuer certificate (see
> http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

My code:

```
$s3 = \Storage::disk('s3');
$filePath = '/images/' . $filename;
$s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image), 'public');
```

Comment: Please visit this link for windows users SSL error.
[Link](https://superuser.com/questions/442793/why-cant-curl-properly-verify-a-certificate-on-windows)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have do a tweak to the php.ini file. Download this file http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and set the path in php.ini like this and then restart the server.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; php.ini Options  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

Above path is common for XAAMP

And that will fix your issue.

Comment: I added cacert.pem file  path in php.ini like this                                         [cURL] 
curl.cainfo='C:\xampp\cacert.pem'                                                                              But still showing same error

Comment: Did you make sure the path matches the location of file

Comment: Yes i am sure have any other step to setting a path?

Comment: Is it windows or linux?

Comment: windows . Now showing another error Error .executing "ListObjects" on "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/soccoapp?prefix=soccoimages%2FIMG-1469844125-j.jpg%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: C:\cacert.pem
CApath: none (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: Add that certificate in the PHP directory and change that path to c:\php\cacert.pem

Comment: Are you using a SDK?

Comment: No i am using xampp

Comment: Ok this is the path the cacert file should go C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem

Comment: Did you add that line or the [curl] also above it just add that line check my edited answer

Comment: yes that also added           [curl]
curl.cainfo ="C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"

Comment: Don't add that [curl] just the path and then restart

Comment: This was my localhost error.when i try to run this code  on the amazon ec2 server .I got a error Class 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter' not found

Comment: Ok now what is the version of flysystem-aws on your laravel

Comment: When Did you got this error 'League\Flysystem\AwsS3v3\AwsS3Adapter'

Comment: I am try to run on the server now.Its a ubuntu ec2 .Verison is  "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0"

Comment: What is the larval version?

Comment: Laravel 5 .Sorry i had a mistake i forget to remove .txt in pem file .Now the existing issue solved then showing another error :(                                           >Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.ap-south->1.amazonaws.com/sapp/soimages/IMG-1469847111-j.jpg"; AWS >HTTP error: Client error: `PUT https://s3.ap-south->1.amazonaws.com/sapp/soimages/IMG-1469847111-j.jpg` resulted in >a `403 Forbidden` response:
><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
><Error><Code>RequestTimeTooSkewed</Code><Message>The >difference between the reque (truncated...)
>RequestTimeTooSkewed (clien

Comment: Ok Now add another question for this issue your SSL issue is solved. And mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
$s3 = new S3Client
         ([
            'version' => 'latest',
            'scheme' =>'http',
            'region'  => $this->config->item('s3_region'),
            'credentials' => [
                'key'    => $this->config->item('s3_access_key'),
                'secret' => $this->config->item('s3_secret_key')
            ],
        ]);
```

Add 'scheme' =>'http' for development.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Error reason is you are working on local or on a not verified server.
Just you need to add the following line to "filesystem.php"

```
'scheme' => 'http' // to disable SSL verification on local development
```

Your filesystem.php should look like this :

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'scheme' => 'http' // to disable SSL verification on local development
        ],
```

When you run it on your server which has SSL verification, you need to comment 'scheme' line.

Try it and you will see it works.
Enjoy your coding !